# How to compute correlation between attributes in python?

Tags: python, scipy

So I have a dataset with 13 attributes + the class attribute and I want to find the correlations. 
After some search I found methods to compute the correlation in a multivariate dataset but the problem is that they work with normally distributed data. I tried doing this:

```
stats.normaltest(ds, None)
```

But it return the p value as 0.0. Is this normal behavior? 
I mean I know if the p is lower than 0.05 it is not a normal distribution but I 've never seen the p value = exactly 0.0

Comment: I'm sure some tags are missing here? will it be scipy? numpy? pandas?

Comment: A.) There are several ways to test for correlation without assuming normality.  Heck, even Pearson's rho [doesn't assume normality](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3733/26579).  B.) The value of p is very dependent on sample size.  How big is your dataset?

Comment: @wflynny My dataset is 504 samples. And actually I looked up the Pearson in Scipy. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html and it says it assumes normality: "Pearson’s correlation requires that each dataset be normally distributed"

Comment: @Ahmedn1 Perhaps Scipy's computation of the p value assumes normality, but in general, while it can be very sensitive to the underlying distribution (i.e. very nonlinear relationships), strict normality is not a necessity.  Furthermore, there always Spearman, Kendall Tau, etc.  To your question, `normaltest` computes the skew and kurtosis of your distribution and uses that to compute a chisq test and p value.  What are the skew and kurtosis of your data?  And have you tried scatter plotting your data to see if you expect correlations?

Comment: That's the result I get from normaltest: (3627.2582951813656, 0.0)
and I will try the other methods you mentioned for correlation.

Comment: Well I tried pearson and spearman and I got different coefficients. That's normal I guess. But I'm still not sure if it is correct for the dataset